boot.ini, boot from primary partitions after extended partition
Is there a (Win NT) rule that MBR primary partitions must come before extended partitions?
Active partition is on rdisk(0)
I've got a secondary drive with 4/5 partitions (depending on how you count it), parted shows:
1 Primary
2 Extended, contains (3) Logical
4 Primary
5 Primary
To boot the logical partition, using boot.ini,
 multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(4)\WINDOWS="14" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect

parted lists all 5 partitions: NTLDR is known to not count the container partition, and to enumerate the logical partition after enumerating the primary partitions, so the logical partition is (4).
So far, I have been unable to load HAL.DLL from the next two primary partitions
 multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(2)\WINDOWS="12" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
 multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(3)\WINDOWS="13" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect

Is this a known problem with NTLDR -- primary partitions must come before extended partitions?  (Or just something I've got wrong somewhere else.)

A vanilla Windows XP/NT is hardly going to recognize more than a single MBR with a maximum of four partitions or one primary and one extended partition. all else is most likely "unsupported" / unexplored territory, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Sector_layout

@Hannu, This question was about only a single extended partition, only the order unusual, but your information is incorrect: XP (with standard XP MBR) recognizes 3 primary and many sequentially embedded Extended partitions, each extended partition containing 2TB split into many partitions.

Well, that makes me wonder how much time you have spent on finding out that...
